# CORS NGINX configuration problem

Tags: 17.04, nginx, https, webdav

I have an Ubuntu web server with NGINX. I want to add CORS support for the following WebDAV methods: `PUT`, `GET`, `OPTIONS`, `MKCOL`, `PROPFIND`. I read couple of articles how to add the CORS support and I have put the following lines in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
#       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;


        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /test {
                add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, MKCOL, PROPFIND';
                add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true";
                add_header  "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Authorization, origin, accept";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
                dav_methods  PUT DELETE MKCOL;
                dav_ext_methods   PROPFIND OPTIONS;
                autoindex     on;
                create_full_put_path on;
                limit_except  GET HEAD {
                allow XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32;
                deny  all;
                }
       }
}
```

But even after restart the nginx server the client is complaining that the CORS is not enabled. I got error messages that `"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'XXXX.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404."`. The interesting part is that I don't get such errors when the file is present, only if it is not there, but on the other hand I am testing the same on another server and on this server when the file is not present I got only `HTTP status code 404`.

And this is my nginx version and installed modules:

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads --add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/nginx-Q158zN/nginx-1.10.3/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```